# Opening a file from .netrw in a specified split

Tags: vim

I have a window split in four; two by two; and in the upper left split netrw is open.

How do I open a file from netrw in split no. 3 (the lower right one)?

Answer (score 3):

You might like to try netrw v153j:

- let g:netrw_chgwin= window number you'd like editing to take place in
- when in a netrw buffer: [count]C will use the count as the window number specifying which window to use for editing
- :NetrwC [winnr] will select the specified window number for subsequent editing

You can get v153j from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW

Comment: So from netrw you can just press `4C<Enter>`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can press `P` to open the file under the cursor in the *previously* focused window.

```
" Focus the fourth window

4 CTRL-W CTRL-W

" Focus the netrw window

1 CTRL-W CTRL-W

" Open the focused file in the fourth window

P
```

This will also focus the opened file.  You could press `CTRL-W p` to return to the netrw window.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in normal mode, you can type this to open "filename" in the lower right window

```
:exe 4 . "wincmd w|e filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

Three possibilities (as stated in [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/768569/992477)):

- `:let g:netrw_chgwin = 3`
- `:NetrwC 3`
- `3C` (only when in Netrw buffer)

If you always want to edit a file in the window from which you gave the command to open Netrw, you can create a function like this:

```
function! MyLexplore()
  let g:netrw_chgwin = winnr() + 1
  :Lexplore
endfunction
```

Netrw will be opened in window 1, so the other window numbers shift one position up. So when Netrw is open, `winnr() + 1` will be the window from which you called `MyLexplore()`.

You can also bind this function to a key:

```
nnoremap E :call MyLexplore()<CR>
```